# pandas join DF - merge vs. join different semantics

Tags: python, pandas, join

I want to join 2 DF in pandas. Some columns are int or float, others are categories. (not enforcing the same cat code/index for categories from A and B df)
Their common columns are a list of float and category columns of size 8.

Joining via

```
df_a.merge(df_b, how='inner'), on=join_columns )
```

will return no result at all. And joining via

```
df_a.join(df_b, lsuffix='_l', rsuffix='_r')
```

Seems to work.

But I am a bit confused why one failed and if I should not cast all columns to object in order to prevent joining by cat codes which could be wrong.

I.e. if `left` is chosen as join method for `merge`, joined columns will only contain `NAN` values. Unfortunately, I am not really sure how t build an useful minimal example.

## edit

here a sample

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
        'nationality': ['DE', 'AUT', 'US', 'US', 'US'],
        'age_group' : [1, 2, 1, 3, 1]}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'name', 'nationality', 'age_group'])
df_a.nationality = df_a.nationality.astype('category')
df_a


raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3' ],
        'name': ['Billy', 'Brian', 'Bran'],
        'nationality': ['DE', 'US', 'US'],
        'age_group' : [1, 1, 3],
        'average_return_per_group' : [1.5, 2.3, 1.4]}
df_b = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'name', 'nationality', 'age_group', 'average_return_per_group'])
df_b.nationality = df_b.nationality.astype('category')
df_b


# some result is joined
df_a.join(df_b, lsuffix='_l', rsuffix='_r') 

# this *fails* as only NULL values joined, or nor result for inner join
df_a.merge(df_b, how='left', on=['nationality', 'age_group'])
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` joins per default along the indexes, and `merge` along the columns with the same names.

Check this:

```
In [115]: df_a.join(df_b, lsuffix='_l', rsuffix='_r')
Out[115]:
  subject_id_l name_l nationality_l  age_group_l subject_id_r name_r nationality_r  age_group_r average_returns_per_group
0            1      A            DE            1            1  Billy            DE          1.0                       NaN
1            2      B           AUT            2            2  Brian            US          1.0                       NaN
2            3      C            US            1            3   Bran            US          3.0                       NaN
3            4      D            US            3          NaN    NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN
4            5      E            US            1          NaN    NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN
```

let's set `['a','b','c']` as an index in `df_b` and try to join it again - you'll see only `NaN`'s in all `*_r` columns:

```
In [116]: df_a.join(df_b.set_index(pd.Index(['a','b','c'])), lsuffix='_l', rsuffix='_r')
Out[116]:
  subject_id_l name_l nationality_l  age_group_l subject_id_r name_r nationality_r  age_group_r average_returns_per_group
0            1      A            DE            1          NaN    NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN
1            2      B           AUT            2          NaN    NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN
2            3      C            US            1          NaN    NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN
3            4      D            US            3          NaN    NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN
4            5      E            US            1          NaN    NaN           NaN          NaN                       NaN

In [117]: df_b.set_index(pd.Index(['a','b','c']))
Out[117]:
  subject_id   name nationality  age_group average_returns_per_group
a          1  Billy          DE          1                       NaN
b          2  Brian          US          1                       NaN
c          3   Bran          US          3                       NaN
```

**UPDATE:** IMO [merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) works as expected (described in docs)

```
In [151]: df_a.merge(df_b, on=['nationality', 'age_group'], how='left', suffixes=['_l','_r'])
Out[151]:
  subject_id_l name_l nationality  age_group subject_id_r name_r  average_return_per_group
0            1      A          DE          1            1  Billy                       1.5
1            2      B         AUT          2          NaN    NaN                       NaN
2            3      C          US          1            2  Brian                       2.3
3            4      D          US          3            3   Bran                       1.4
4            5      E          US          1            2  Brian                       2.3
```

Comment: I see, but this would not produce a useful result if I want to join on values? I.e. A is very long and B contains some additional metadata I want to lookup / join .

Comment: @GeorgHeiler, please provide sample reproducible data sets

Comment: I added a sample dataset

Comment: @GeorgHeiler, check your `df_b['average_returns_per_group']` - it contains all `NaN`'s !

Comment: But index `3` of `df_a` contains `3 C US 1` and index `2` of `df_b` contains `2 Brian US 1 2.3` so when joining on `nationality` and `age_group` there should be at least a single match? Why are these missing? Yes sorry, I fixed that. Was a singular/ plural mistake for the colname. Still I do not see why the match mentioned above is not showing up.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler, do you mean using `join` or `merge`?

Comment: I mean merge, but could observe now with the *fixed* example, that the join works. I still wonder if category values with same value but different index cat code number are treated correctly, but for this minimal example this seems to work fine. ... the annoying thing is  that this means I probably have an issue with my real data, as I still see the problem there.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler, check whether you have duplicates in "merging" columns - they will result in cartesian product. Beside that check that the values in "merging" columns are identical

Comment: I started to check this. for the first column that seemed to hold true. I will continue working on this problem tomorrow and update you here. Will mark your Question as correct already today as it was a great explanation of join vs merge and works fine on the sample data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141938/discussion-between-georg-heiler-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1):

I think main difference is `join` have default `left join` and `merge` `inner join.`

Comment: Sure, but as outlined if choosing `left` for `merge` the columns are joined, but the result are simply NAN values, where join produces some output which looks reasonable at first glance.

Comment: Hmmm, can you add data? Maybe it can find problem easier.

Comment: I added a sample dataset